# PHP Laravel get millions record using MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, relational-database, laravel-4.2

I have been using laravel + mysql for my project but and it was working perfectly fine until now. The records keep on increasing and now they have reached almost a million record. Problem is when i try to fetch sms from my database using this query

```
 $smsHistory = SmsLog::where('created_at', '>=', $startDate)->where('created_at', '<=', $endDate)->whereNotNull('gateway_statuscode')->get();
```

It gives a 500 error without showing anything in error log. What i assume is that as i decreased the time period it gives me record so the problem is the bulk it can not handle. What could be the possible solution as i have to give it today.

I am not worried about the error log.. i want to get a count of those million record but i want to apply some algorithm on it before doing it

This is the check which i have to perform afterwards to see how many sms are in sms log

```
 foreach ($smsHistory as $sms) {
        $sms_content = SmsService::_getSmsContent($sms);
        if ($sms_content->business_id && array_key_exists($sms_content->business_id, $smsCredits )) {
            if (floor(strlen($sms_content->content) / 160) == 0) {
                $smsCredits[$sms_content->business_id]['count'] += 1;
            }

            if (floor(strlen($sms_content->content) / 160) == 1 && floor(strlen($sms_content->content) / 306) == 0) {
                $smsCredits[$sms_content->business_id]['count'] += 2;
            }

            if (floor(strlen($sms_content->content) / 306) == 1 && floor(strlen($sms_content->content) / 459) == 0) {
                $smsCredits[$sms_content->business_id]['count'] += 3;
            }

            if (floor(strlen($sms_content->content) / 459) == 1 && floor(strlen($sms_content->content) / 621) == 0) {
                $smsCredits[$sms_content->business_id]['count'] += 4;
            }

            if (floor(strlen($sms_content->content) / 621) == 1 && floor(strlen($sms_content->content) / 774) == 0) {
                $smsCredits[$sms_content->business_id]['count'] += 5;
            }

            if (floor(strlen($sms_content->content) / 774) == 1 && floor(strlen($sms_content->content) / 927) == 0) {
                $smsCredits[$sms_content->business_id]['count'] += 6;
            }
        }
```

this is the database field [image]

content is the sms that i have to get and count

Comment: One million record in a single query? You can use pagination load limited data as needed not all rows in a single query

Comment: I want to get a count of those values.. what do you suggest

Comment: There are builtin count method in laravel

Comment: Check out: https://www.laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#aggregates

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding the 500 error:**
If you are getting a 500 error, there should hopefully be some clue in the actual server error log (your laravel application error log may not have caught it depending on the error handlers, etc and what the cause was). php_info() should show you the location of the physical error log with the *error_log* setting:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

If I had to guess, possibly something memory related that is causing it to choke. But that is just a guess.

As a side question, why are you trying to retrieve so many at once? Can you split them up somehow?

**Edit based on updated question:**
You may need to use some raw-expressions here to get what you really want: https://www.laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#raw-expressions

MySQL for example provides the ability to get a column length:
FLOOR(CHAR_LENGTH(content) / 160) as len1, FLOOR(CHAR_LENGTH(content) / 306) as len2, FLOOR(CHAR_LENGTH(content) / 459) as len3

So probably with some magic we could take your query and let the database system do it all for you. And there are probably more efficient ways to do it, if I knew more about the significance of those numbers, but I am trying to help you at least get on one possible path.

Comment: I am not worried about the error log.. i want to get a count of those million record but i want to apply some algorithm on it before doing it

Comment: What sort of algorithm do you want to apply before counting?

Comment: i want to check the sms lengths according to some format before adding the count 

i.e 
160 1 sms 
306 2 sms 
622 3 sms 

go on

Comment: What do your columns look like? Let's say your query does work for the smaller ones where you don't have so many results, do you have the code that you're doing to it afterwards that we can look at to see if we can help you put it into the sql query itself?

Comment: yeah its a text field. the database was built by someone else it is very poorly built. let me show u..

Comment: There are some more references to possibly help with migrating more of the processing to the database.

Comment: its not even getting the data without any processing , hows it going to work with some processing

Answer (score 0):

You should setup index for mysql, or implement a search engine like elastic search

Comment: *implement a search engine like elastic search* ... that reads like a terrible comment, but is in no way a reasonable answer!